# How to check if my input is in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm programming a word game in Html/Javscript. 
You need to guess the word. When a letters is right, then the letter will get a green background (this works).
But now I want that if the letter is in the word, but not in the right position, the background will be yellow (this is the issue)

```
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { 
  if(rand[i] == input[i].value.toUpperCase()) {                     
    if(countClick == 1) {
      // Here the background will become green when its correct
      input[i].value = rand[i];
      var input1 = document.hetForm.L01;
      input1[i].value = rand[i];
      input[i].style.background = "green";
      input1[i].style.background = "green";                 
    }

    if(countClick == 2) {
      input[i].value = rand[i];
      var input2 = document.hetForm.L02;
      input2[i].value = rand[i];
      input[i].style.background = "green";
      input2[i].style.background = "green";
    }

    if(countClick == 3) {
      input[i].value = rand[i];
      var input3 = document.hetForm.L03;
      input3[i].value = rand[i];
      input[i].style.background = "green";
      input3[i].style.background = "green";
    }

    if(countClick == 4) {
      input[i].value = rand[i];
      var input4= document.hetForm.L04;
      input4[i].value = rand[i];
      input[i].style.background = "green";
      input4[i].style.background = "green";
    }

    if(countClick == 5) {
      input[i].value = rand[i];
      input[i].style.background = "green";
    }

    // If it is the right letter, put green background on it
    input[i].style.background = "green";
    good++;
  } else {
    if(rand.indexOf(invoer[i].value)) {
      input[i].style.background = "yellow";
    } else {
      alert(input[i].value);    
    }
  }
}
```

rand is a random value of my array (with all the words in it).

The code needs to give every letter that is not in the right position a yellow background.

Comment: `if(rand.indexOf(invoer[i].value) > -1)` ? - `if(-1){alert('true')}` will be true, even though `-1` should be false and `if(0){alert('true')}` is false, even though `0` should be true, so eitherway you should probably check against `-1` and not just `if(true)` I think.

Comment: @Fran No still the same fault

Comment: I don't think your question title is at all descriptive of your actual question...

Comment: He's trying to check if the value of an input is found in an array... We can hardly do better.

Comment: If rand == "senses" and you guess `EEEEEE` there are two green Es and.,..four yellow Es?  or two green Es and no yellow Es?  Because in the second case you have to keep track of which spaces have already been guessed correctly.

Comment: @K.vandenBerg As said, either way, you need to validate against `-1` as that will be part your issue.

Comment: I forgot the -1 and the toUpperCase(). Now its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine, the problem is the test you are doing that is wrong. indexOf returns the index where it was found in the array, or -1. Since the indexes start at 0, and you are testing for truthy value, this will always be correct unless the letter is found in the first index of the array... Correct your if with this:

```
if(rand.indexOf(invoer[i].value.toUpperCase())>-1)
```

Also, like you done in your upper IF statement, use `.toUpperCase()` too if the case does not matter. Your code does not show it, but I presume rand has been populated with capitals...

Answer (score 1):

an alternative to your code:

```
var rand = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
var input = "BEND";

for (var index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {

    var colorCode = getColorCodeForInputLetter(index, input[index]);
    console.log(input[index], "=>", colorCode);

}

function getColorCodeForInputLetter(index, letter) {

    // Check if the letter is in the rand Array
    if (rand.indexOf(letter) !== -1) {

        // Check if the index of the letter is equals to the index of the letter in the array
        if (rand.indexOf(letter) === index) {
            console.log(letter, "correct");
            return "green";
        } else {
            console.log(letter, "in rand");
            return "yellow";
        }

    } else {
        console.log(letter, "not in rand");
        return "red";
    }

}
```

I've rand this in node and the output is:

```
B in rand
E not in rand
N not in rand
D correct
```